# Devise redirect path after sign-up and before confirmation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, devise-confirmable

I have implemented the devise gem on my app and I want to redirect to a specific path after sign_up. I have this method in the registration_controller.rb but its does not work, it redirects to the root path instead of the specified path. I also have `devise :confirmable` set up but I'm delaying the sent confirmation email until later.

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  new_transaction_path(session[:registration_params])
end
```

And returns the following flash notice: `translation missing: en.devise.registrations.store.signed_up_but`

How can I make this work?

Comment: what is in session[:registration_params] ? may be you need to pass resource

Comment: you can also try def `after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    new_transaction_path(resource)
  end`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Vishal.... I'm adding parameters in a query string to a path that it's new_store_registration, and storing them in a sessions  when hitting the new action in the store_registration controller and then retrieve them in the after_sign_up_path_for method.

Comment: The `def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource) new_transaction_path(session[:registration_params]) end` redirects me to the correct path but does not keep the params

Comment: may be you don't have any params in `session[:registration_params] `. try to send `params[:registration]` when you hit sign up button that time in rails server log you can check how params pass in sign up method

Answer (score 0):

You must be over riding the method in another file. Try searching project wide for after_sign_in_path_for. I have the following in my application controller working perfectly:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def after_sign_in_path_for(*)
    cms_path
  end
end
```

Where cms_path is a named route in my routes file. If yours isn't working you must be over riding it somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by adding the following on the registration_controller.rb

```
def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  new_transaction_path(session[:registration_params])
end
```